# passing parameters from the bash script

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to pass the value of a variable from my bash script as argument for the CLI of a package.

```
patt_gen -del -s 10 -o delaychange -f delay.txt
```

Here I actually want to pass the value 10 which is the value of the variable size in my bash script.

Comment: Are you calling that command within the script itself ? Is that command part of the script ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `$foo` to get the value of variable `foo`. So:

```
patt_gen -del -s "$size" -o delaychange -f delay.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Muru. It worked. Yesterday I tried this but did not work. I suppose I would have done some mistake yesterday.